# IdentityServer4 signout MVC5 App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver4

following [Issue 1](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1121#issuecomment-85997712) and [Issue 2](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/627) I cant sign out from IS4. Local ASP.NET cookies are not removed and I cannot re-login to IS4.

It works for Core MVC app, but for MVC5 does not.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "TRUX.NET",
        Authority = baseAddress,
        RedirectUri = $"http://localhost:2510/signin-oidc",
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = $"http://localhost:2510/signout-callback-oidc",
        ResponseType = "code id_token",
        Scope = "openid profile offline_access custom.profile AuthorizationWebApi Common.WebApi",

        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role"
        },

        SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
--------
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");
                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
```

Server config

```
            new Client
        {
            ClientId = "MVC50",
            ClientName = "MVC50 APP",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
            RequireConsent = false,
            ClientSecrets= {new Secret("123456".Sha256()) },
            RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:2510/signin-oidc" }, 
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:2510/signout-callback-oidc"},
            AllowedScopes = {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "custom.profile",
                "AuthorizationWebApi",
                "Common.WebApi"
            },
            AllowOfflineAccess = true                    
        }
```

If any one can help, i'll appreciate.
regards.

Update :

1. I removed signout-callback-oidc from both server and client configs.
2. My signout action is this one

   ```
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignOut()
   {
     Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(); 
     return Redirect("/");
   }
   ```
3. Undeterministically I can call end session endpoint. The logs are given below.
4. id_token_hint is not null

   |1|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|INFO|Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://www.abcdef.com:5000/connect/endsession?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a2510%2f&id_token_hint=(hint)
   |1|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|DEBUG|OPTIONS requests are not supported 
   |0|IdentityServer4.CorsPolicyProvider|DEBUG|CORS request made for path: /connect/endsession from origin: http://localhost:2510 but rejected because invalid CORS path 
   |9|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware|DEBUG|AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated. 
   |0|IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter|DEBUG|Request path /connect/endsession matched to endpoint type EndSession 
   |0|IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter|DEBUG|Mapping found for endpoint: EndSession, creating handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint 
   |0|IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware|INFO|Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint for /connect/endsession 
   |0|IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionEndpoint|WARN|Invalid HTTP method for end session endpoint. 
   |0|IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware|TRACE|Invoking result: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.StatusCodeResult 
   |9|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|DEBUG|Connection id "0HL3SPFTNB2FH" completed keep alive response. 
   |2|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|INFO|Request finished in 1322.3713ms 405

Comment: @JonasAxelsson I need your help again =-$ , as i remember you were implementing "non-core mvc client". IS4 ie really difficult to configure :(. thanks and regards

Comment: I have the same issue, can't end IS4 session on MVC5 client (it seems to work but when navigating to a secure page, the user is still logged in, the IS4 login page is not displayed). I tried same solution as ozgurozkanakdemirci and also trying to redirect to the endsession endpoint but in this case, I need the id_token_hint to ba able to redirect the user back to the client and can't get this id_token, client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync always return unauthorized access.  any help? sample code code for the logout action please. thanks

Comment: @Webmixer is this what you need? And did you check PostLogoutRedirectUri setting ?


RedirectToIdentityProvider = n => {// if signing out, add the id_token_hint

if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
{
var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");
if (idTokenHint != null)
{
n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
}
else
{
_logger.Info($"idTokenHint is null... ");
}
}
return Task.FromResult(0);
}

Comment: Thanks, the issue was that the i_token always return null... I updated my config to correctly get the id_token with user claims and then the postlogoutredirect works when this IdToken is passed as id_token_hint.